# OS X Mavericks - hybrid hibernate does not work?

Tags: macos, hibernate

I have MacBook Pro, late 2010.
For a while I was using OS X 10.6 and sleep logic was next:
1. after closing lid macbook go to sleep (with momentary wake up on lid open)
2. after day or so of sleeping macbook changes it state to hiberante (ram2diskc I suppose). wake up should be performed with power button and it will take some time (like several minutes or so)

Recently I've upgraded my macbook with 8gb ram and ssd + OS X Mavericks. After closing lid macbook will go to sleep, but in my case it was "sleeping" for 3 days without hibernation (and about ~40% of battery was used). On ohter hand, Mavericks has option `resume apps state after shutdown` and it works almost nice except I would really prefer to have hibernate instead (e.g. I need state of my terminal with open programs/running commands inside it, some background services running, etc).

Answer (score 1):

To see what the current sleep mode is (in Terminal):

```
pmset -g | grep hibernatemode
```

To change the sleep mode to hibernate:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

To set back to the default:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3
```

More info: [tutsplus - how to hibernate a mac](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-hibernate-a-mac--cms-23235)